# JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Unauthorized': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I am using `ObjectMapper.readValue(String, Map.Class)` to deserialize the response received from a 3rd party REST API. I get

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
>   'Unauthorized': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') for a
>   response (401) with body "Unauthorized".

I didn't find any `deserializeFeature` property to help with the above issue or may be there is something, but I haven't understood. Could somebody help?

Comment: The  error response is not in JSON format; presumably the content-type header would tell you that.

Comment: Right... I should just check the content-type. Thanks!